# Entity Framework Querying on Independent Associations create overly complicated queries?

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-5

I'm creating a project using EF5 and code first.

In my object design i have used **"Independent Associations"** in this case the property "FarmWhereCowLives" is an **"Independent Association"**.

```
public class Cow

{

     public int CowId
     public string Name
     public DateTime Birthday
     public Farm FarmWhereCowLives
}

public class Farm

{

     public int FarmId
     public string Name
     public string Suburb
}
```

Yet when I go to run a query asking Entity Framework to select the newest cow for a particular farm by passing in the farm id... for example:

```
_dbset.AsQueryable().Where(c => c.FarmWhereCowLives.FarmId == 1).OrderByDescending(c => c.Birthday).Take(1).Single()
```

(I'm using generic repository just in case that's relevant but I don't think so)

The sql that is executed (i can see it in SQL profiler) seems overly complicated?

Eg

```
SELECT TOP (1) 
[Project1].[CowId] AS [CowId], 
[Project1].[Name] AS [Name], 
[Project1].[Birthday] AS [Birthday],  
[Project1].[FarmWhereCowLives_FarmId] AS [FarmWhereCowLives_FarmId]
FROM 

(

    SELECT 
[Extent1].[RateChangeId] AS [RateChangeId], 
    [Extent1].[CowId] AS [CowId], 
    [Extent1].[Name] AS [Name], 
    [Extent1].[Birthday] AS [Birthday],  
    [Extent1].[FarmWhereCowLives_FarmId] AS [FarmWhereCowLives_FarmId]
FROM [dbo].[Cow] AS [Extent1]
WHERE [Extent1].[FarmWhereCowLives_FarmId] = 1

)  

AS [Project1]

ORDER BY [Project1].[Birthday] DESC'
```

Questions would be:

1. What's with the nested select?
2. Why didn't EF write a more efficient query? eg without the nested select?
3. Should I add a foreign key association for the cow object? I shouldn't have to do this to get EF to execute a well written query, should I?

Maybe I'm doing something wrong here?

Cheers
Andrew

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EF always uses nested queries - I somehow expect it will use nested query for FK association as well. It doesn't necessarily mean that query is not correct. Query optimizer in database can simplify the query before execution.